# Slimscroll not working with Jquery 2.1.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

I am using jquery slimscroll plugin for a division using jquery 2.1.0 but doesn't work with it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS:

```
#m-data{
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id=m-data>
    <h3>Hello world have a good day!</h3>
    <h3>Hello world have a good day!</h3>
    <h3>Hello world have a good day!</h3>
    <h3 class=last>Hello world have a good day!</h3>
</div>
```

JQ/JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#m-data').slimScroll({
        height: '250px',
        width: '300px',
        start: 'bottom',
        disableFadeOut: true,
        distance: '-1px',
        size: '9px'
    });
});
```

Complete code available here: http://jsfiddle.net/h4YyX/1/

Comment: Your jsfiddle has syntax errors.

Comment: will you please explain?

Comment: If you provide an example you should make sure that it does not contain any syntax errors. If I just copy your code, and include the `slimscroll` plugin along with jQuery 2.1 it works. You alway need to check the console of your browser to see if no error happens. If a error is displayed and you are not able to solve that, then show this error with your question.

Comment: I don't see any syntax error on my localhost with downgraded version of Jquery...

Comment: Since it work for you, it means it works fine with Jquery 2.1 so might be I am making blunder somewhere, its okay I will go through the code again, Any way thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see that your example does not work when updated to load the error free version from a CDN  [jsfiddle.net/h4YyX/2](http://jsfiddle.net/h4YyX/2/).

Comment: But you **really** should learn how to use and interpret the console. No matter if it was a syntax error or a wrong order in loading the plugin, there definitely was an error in the console of your browser. Either a syntax error or something like `undefined is not a function`.